# Enroll visitor in Sitecore Engagement Plan programmatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I would like to Enroll a Sitecore visitor in a specific state of an engagement plan through code. Can't find how to do this in the documentation.

Anyone?

Answer (score 5):

Found it through the help of the great Sitecore Support staff.

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.VisitorManager.AddVisitor(userName, stateId);
```

You have to reference "Sitecore.Automation.MarketingAutomation.dll" in your project.

Comment: What is the explaination of the parameters? Is username equal to visitorId? And is stateId the SitecoreId of a state inside an engagement plan? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, the userName is the qualified Sitecore username. and the stateId is the Sitecore ID of the initial state of an engagement plan. More information found here: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/programming-for-sitecore-dms-engagement-plans/

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore 8.1 Automation API has changed and now is using AutomationStateManager to manage the engagement plans from code.

```
automationContext.MoveToEngagementState(planId, stateId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the contact is not in the Engagement Plan, for Sitecore 8.1 you can use this code to enroll it:

```
 AutomationStateManager manager = Tracker.Current.Session.CreateAutomationStateManager();
 manager.EnrollInEngagementPlan([engagement plan id], [state id]);

 manager.SaveChanges(AutomationManager.Provider)
```